# Create user with admin option oracle 11g command not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

okay , This command is not working

`create user  username identified by password  with admin option ;`

It throws an error which says `missing or invalid option`

And  i am logged in as system .   I have tried searching Oracle docs and they have written the same command . what i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to first create the user;

```
CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY password;
```

then separately grant privileges with ADMIN OPTION;

```
GRANT dba TO username WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Comment: oh yes my bad reading the docs . and where u have written `dba` ,what difference shall it make if we write system_priveleges instead ?

Comment: @kushal dba was just an example, some possible roles and their uses are listed at http://psoug.org/reference/roles.html or you can grant system privileges listed at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#i2077938 The only thing "with admin option" does is to not just allow the user into the role but also to administrate it.

Comment: @kushal Yes, your statement will work and insert `cash` from _all rows_ into `tablename` (setting column `amount`). You can of course add a regular `where` clause to choose which rows to insert.

Comment: sorry , i accidently deleted the comment above . So i am wrirting the query again `insert into students(amount) select cash from payments; ` 
Okay i tried running this . I have a `students` tables with column `rollno` as primary key and same column as a foreign key in `payments` table and when i ran this command error says cannot insert NULL into students.rollno . the thing is payments contain multiple entries for a single rollno (depending on their date of payemnt ) .

Comment: But i cant really understand the error thrown here. shouldn't error be saying  something like "multiple entries for a rollno ,so cannot be inserted ".

Comment: @kushal Well, your insert will _only set amount_ in the new row inserted, no other column. In other words, rollno is inserted as null and that won't work for a primary key. A primary key myst be unique and not null. You may want `INSERT INTO students(amount, rollno) SELECT ...` or similar. You may want to start a new question if you need help with a complicated query.

Comment: How do I grant view all tables object permission to this new user.

Answer (score 3):

"ADMIN OPTION" is a part of "GRANT" statement. You can't use it with "CREATE USER".

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to give admin option if you are giving user DBA privilege ,DBA is the administrator 
Also you can combine both statements Creation of user with Grant privilege:

create user username
identified by password
grant DBA to username;

Note:Correct me if I am wrong.☺